# How can we calculate the HTTP request made by each web page of my website

Tags: java, php, http, httprequest

can any one please help me to count how many HTTP request has to be made when i open my website [Cricket News](http://www.cricandcric.com)

I am trying to increase the performance and better loading on all browsers.

1 more questions
1) How many Http Requests is better for better performance?

Comment: The number of HTTP requests made by a browser is subjective to various parameters. It depends on both the browser and server configuration. There is only one way to find out if you can extract more performance out of the server and the connection - use a web traffic monitor like Fiddler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firefox extensions [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) are an excellent way to determine this sort of metric. YSlow will give you additional optimization suggestions based on what it sees from your site.

Edit: To answer your second question, fewer HTTP requests are always better than more. There is no magic number. You have to balance doing everything you need to do in the fewest requests possible with maintainability of your code.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have installed Firebug and installed Yslow also, i can analyse my web performance right away.
Is there any other Add on, that i need to install apart from firebug and Yslow?

Comment: @harigm, Those are the two that I use (and the web developer toolbar, but that's unrelated to what you are wanting to see).

Comment: @Jason, If i run the yslow, the HTTP request made by my home page www.cricandcric.com, keep changing every time, 
If I see Tushar response below, when he ran the test, he got 99 HTTP request, when I ran the Yslow test, I got one time 145 HTTP request and other time i got 138 HTTP rquest, why is that i am getting the different number every time? I am not changing any thing on the home page

Comment: @harigm, caching, probably. If you disable caching in firefox you should see the same number of requests each time (assuming you aren't making requests programatically.)

Comment: @jason, i think you are correct that might be because of caching?

Comment: @jason, If you can help please help me on the other question at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491216/clarification-required-on-content-encoding-and-its-effect-on-the-web-portal

Answer (score 2):

I could see there are a total of 99 requests going through for the home page. I used **firebug** plugin in firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) to check the number of requests. It also gives you time required for each of the request to get served. Quite a useful tool for debugging purposes.

If there is no hard requirement of programatically finding out the number of requests then you can live with it.